# what does to_float in Erlang return ,what is the structure of the tuple it returns?

Tags: erlang

Recently I came across a code snippet which take string as input and returns float value but I'm getting confused with lines inside 3 and 4   construct. Anyone please, explain it.

```
as_number(S) ->  
  case string:to_float(S) of  
    {error, no_float} -> list_to_integer(S);  
    {N, _} -> N  
  end.
```

Comment: You do know there is language documentation, right? http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#to_float-1 The only way this question will survive is if you rephrase it to read more like "How is matching used in Erlang to assert successful return values?" That is actually a decent question about a core concept of the *language*, one not *so obviously* unresearched as asking someone to tell you the typespec of a standard library function. Hit *any* search engine with "Erlang string:to_float" and you will get the string module docs first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `string:to_float` takes in a string (which is a list in erlang) and tries to convert it to a float. It expects valid text that represents a float (ASCII digits), followed by the rest of the string. The return is a tuple of `{Float, Rest}` or `{error, Reason}`, Rest is the remaining part of the string which is not ASCII digits. In this instance, if the string can not be converted to a float, it tries to convert the list to an integer, which may not work, depending on the contents of the string.